# using Moq to implement a method that accepts no parameters and returns void

Tags: c#, moq, void

I am new to Moq and have what seems to be a simple problem.

I have two interfaces - IClient and IClientFactory, whose methods look like this:

```
public interface IClientFactory 
{
  IClientHandler Get(TcpClient tcpClient);
}

public interface IClient 
{
  void Run();
}
```

The implemented Run() method currently opens a stream and send/receives messages. 
I am trying to test my Server class, particularly the Listen method.
How can I mock this so that my Server class accepts a client and receives a message from it?

This is the code in my Server class:

```
public void Listen(CancellationToken cancellation)
{
    listener.Start(_maxConnections);
    //.... Accept Tcp Client here ....
    var handler = _handlerFactory.Get(client); <--- GET CLIENT HERE
    //.... Start Communication ....
}
```

Comment: How do you mean receive a message?

Comment: What you need to do is make `TcpClient` testable. So your best bet is to wrap it in a facade that backs onto an interface.

Comment: The most likely answer is to mock `TcpClient` as suggested by @CallumLinington. I think you also need to provide some more code from the server class. The current snippet is limited and makes the question too broad.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a mock of `IHandlerClient` that does what you want. That entirely depends on what the Listen method will do with the `IHandlerClient`, which you didn't show.
2. So now you have your `handlerClientMock`, setup your `IHandlerFactory` mock so that its Get method returns that mock.

```
var mock = new Mock();
mock.Setup(f => f.Get(It.IsAny()))
    .Returns(handlerClientMock.Object);
```

Now you can create your Server object passing along that `IHandlerFactory` mock.

Comment: I do have a mock of IClient, but I am not sure how to create an implementation so that when the server calls _client.Run()_, it runs the Run() method from the mocked class.